# SELECT to return all items in one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

items table

```
ID    item_id     item
------------------------
1     44          shoe 
2     44          boat
3     44          car
4     82          truck
5     82          shirt
6     82          tree
7     99          egg
8     99          carrot
9     99          penguin
```

So I do:

```
SELECT item 
FROM items 
WHERE item_id = 82
```

I get the following on different rows:

```
 truck
 shirt
 tree
```

Is there a SELECT that will return ALL items in one row , possibly 
separated by some delimiter:

```
truck,shirt,tree
```

I know how to do it the long way but is there a simple select to do the same thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
     [item_id],
     STUFF(
         (SELECT ',' + [item]
          FROM TableName
          WHERE [item_id] = a.[item_id] AND item_id = 82
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS NamesList
FROM TableName AS a
WHERE item_id = 82
GROUP BY [item_id]
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9a43f/7)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CROSS APPLY` and `FOR XML PATH`:

```
SELECT distinct t1.item_id,
  LEFT(itemList , LEN(itemList)-1) itemList 
FROM items t1
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT t2.item + ', '
  FROM items t2
  where t1.item_id = t2.item_id
  FOR XML PATH('')
) m (itemList)
where t1.item_id = 82
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4ef43/2)